# CodeMirror vertical offset at cursor

Tags: codemirror

I have a CodeMirror window whose element's height is set to auto. The max height is set such that it does not add a scroll bar to the page itself. My problem is that when this max height is reached, any subsequent line additions is hidden until I scroll down manually. I would like additional lines to be shown when added by default, thus I'm looking for a vertical offset for the editor, similar to Vim's scrolloff. That is, I always want the lines above and below the cursor to be displayed.

I've come across `cursorScrollMargin` and played around with a few values, but no noticeable changes occur.

Comment: `cursorScrollMargin` only works if there is actual space to scroll into view below the cursor. Maybe enabling the `scrollpastend` addon gives the effect you're looking for?

Comment: @Marijn Hi I just tried `scrollpastend` and also `preserveScrollPosition`, but there seems to be no changes. Thanks for the suggestion though.